# SSRS expression to pull data (today, week, month, year, total) from SP calendar

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a report I'd like to display against my SharePoint calendar. I'd like to display a COUNT/SUM of items and entries for but having problems display correct data. Anyone able to help?

TODAY

```
=Count(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIF(Fields!End_Time.Value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Today, 1, 0), "Data Source")
```

WEEK

```
=SUM(IIF(DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Fields!End_Time.Value)=
DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Today),1,0),"Data Set")
```

MONTH

```
=Sum(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIF(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.MONTH(Fields!End_Time.Value) = Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Today.Month(), 1, 0), "Data Set")
```

YEAR

```
=Sum(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIF(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.YEAR(Fields!End_Time.Value) = Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Today.Year(), 1, 0), "Data Set")
```

TOTAL

```
=Count(Fields!ID.Value, "Data Set")
```

*Edit: inserted screenshot.*

There are only few items that's suppose to show but it's showing 10x that. Look at below screenshot and notice the big numbers.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What's incorrect about what is being returned? Can you give a sample data set and let us know what is being returned compared to what is expected?

Comment: There are only few items that's suppose to show but it's showing 10x that. Look at below screenshot and notice the big numbers.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNOnc.jpg